# New install of Android Studio 3.2.1 create basic project error

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

When installing Android studio and then creating a basic project with a basic `Activity` this is what happens, look at the pictures:

Invalidating cache and Restart in the File menu makes no changes.
I uninstall Android Studio making sure all folders are gone like C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio3.2
Installing a fresh copy Android Studio 3.2.1 but still this error

ERROR OUTPUT

[image: ERROR OUTPUT]

DUBLICATE MENU ITEMS

[image]

MISSING AVD and SDK

[image]

MAKE MAKE
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under Build, click on Build APK(s). If you do not have APKs installed, install them. There is Generate APK under Build too. Check your Gradle files for any added repositories you need to use. Also check that you have installed SDK of your choice.